# Navigation with multiple items, add class and remove class on click

Tags: jquery

I have a navigation with 6 items, basically I want to add a class of active-nav to whichever li is clicked, which I can then use to fire an animation on that particular li. Although it's easy to add that class, I need that class to be removed when another li is clicked, and the class to then be added to the newly clicked li.

```
<nav>
  <div id="navigation">
    <ul>
      <li id="button-1"><button>1</button></li>
      <li id="button-2"><button>2</button></li>
      <li id="button-3"><button>3</button></li>
      <li id="button-4"><button>4</button></li>
      <li id="button-5"><button>5</button></li>
      <li id="button-6"><button>6</button></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="outline"></div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Basically, if i click #button-1, I need to add an active class to that, but if I then click #button-4, I need to remove the class from #button-1 and now add it to #button-4

Comment: What have you tried / found out so far?

Answer (score 0):

```
<nav>
  <div>
    <ul id="navigation">
      <li id="button-1" onclick="setActive('button-1')"><button>1</button></li>
      <li id="button-2" onclick="setActive('button-2')"><button>2</button></li>
      <li id="button-3" onclick="setActive('button-3')"><button>3</button></li>
      <li id="button-4" onclick="setActive('button-4')"><button>4</button></li>
      <li id="button-5" onclick="setActive('button-5')"><button>5</button></li>
      <li id="button-6" onclick="setActive('button-6')"><button>6</button></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="outline"></div>
  </div>
</nav>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function setActive(button){
      $("#navigation").children().removeClass("active");
      $("#" + button).addClass("active");
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

By modifying the HTML to look like this:

```
<nav>
  <div id="navigation">
    <ul id="navigation-ul">
      <li id="button-1" class="active"><button>1</button></li>
      <li id="button-2"><button>2</button></li>
      <li id="button-3"><button>3</button></li>
      <li id="button-4"><button>4</button></li>
      <li id="button-5"><button>5</button></li>
      <li id="button-6"><button>6</button></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="outline"></div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

I can then use this jQuery to accomplish my original task:

```
  $('#navigation-ul').on('click', 'li', function() {
      $('#navigation-ul li.active').removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');
  });
```